# Как вставить строку в таблицу MySQL с проверкой на дубликаты? INSERT INTO / WHERE NOT EXISTS в MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert

Всем привет, пытаюсь вставить в таблицу новую запись, с проверкой дубликата.

После исполнения запроса, у меня создается 42 000 записей....не могу понять почему.

Просьба подсказать верный синтаксис.

Использую следующий запрос:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (pid,num,korp,ext_id,ext_jk_id,ext_corpus_name,ext_corpus_id) 
  SELECT 3242,0,'8.2','CODE1','7874','8.2','93110' 
      FROM flats WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ext_id='CODE1' AND ext_corpus_id='93110' AND ext_jk_id ='7874');
```

Как мне видится, логика запроса такая:
*Вставить в таблицу table_name в колонки* (pid,num,korp,ext_id,ext_jk_id,ext_corpus_name,ext_corpus_id) *данные* 3242,0,'8.2','CODE1','7874','8.2','93110' *если нет совпадения в той же самой таблице table_name полю ext_id с таким же значением*

Логика которую нужно реализовать простая: вставить в таблицу строчку с такими то данными, если в таблице нет строчки с полем, которое соответствует такому-то ИДшнику (поле ext_id, оно уникальное для всех строчек)

Comment: 42k записей создаётся из-за того, что ровно такое количество записей подходят критериям выборки `FROM flats WHERE NOT EXISTS`. Используйте или проверку на бэкенде, или [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205207/4496422)

Comment: Обратите внимание, что ваш not exists сейчас копирует все записи таблицы в случае если искомая одна запись существует. у вас же подзапрос не коррелированный, т.е. он для любой записи таблицыв при срабатывании выдает один и тот же результат. вообще не ясно зачем тут используется not exists почему условия не применяются в основном where

Comment: Просьба пояснить мысль чуть подробнее. Дополнил "логику запроса русским языком", как понимаю запрос, ясно понимаю, что с синтаксисом где-то ошибаюсь, интерпретируя не так, не могу понять где.

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно предполагаю важе желание добавить не достающие записи

```
INSERT INTO table_name (pid,num,korp,ext_id,ext_jk_id,ext_corpus_name,ext_corpus_id) 
  SELECT flats.pid, flats.num, flats.korp, flats.ext_id, flats.ext_jk_id, flats.ext_corpus_name, flats.ext_corpus_id 
      FROM flats 
      left join table_name on 
        table_name.ext_id = flats.ext_id and table_name.ext_corpus_id = flats.ext_corpus_id AND table_name.ext_jk_id = flats.ext_jk_id
      where table_name.pid is null
```

Comment: Видимо ввёл в заблуждение тем, что вначале указал INSERT INTO table_name, а потом исопльзовал значение flats для таблицы ) Приношу извинение. Логика которую нужно реализовать простая: вставить в таблицу строчку с такими то данными, если в таблице нет строчки с полем, которое соответствует такому-то ИДшнику